# How can a locked C# Random get corrupted?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

I am using C# [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8) to generate random numbers in a multi threaded scenario. According to the recommendation [here by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8#the-systemrandom-class-and-thread-safety), I am using a static shared Random object for all the callers and is calling random.Next in a lock.

```cs
        private static TimeSpan GetRandomJitter(IReadOnlyCollection<TimeSpan> timeSpans)
        {
            lock (s_randomizerLock)
            {
                int random = s_randomizerAcrossTenants.Next(timeSpans.Count);
                return timeSpans.ElementAt(random);
            }
        }
```

But in the example Microsoft provided in the [same page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8#the-systemrandom-class-and-thread-safety), They are using an additional check to see if the random is corrupted even then they have a lock for the usages of `Next()`

```cs
private void GetRandomNumbers(Object o)
   {
      CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken) o;
      double result = 0.0;
      countdown.AddCount(1);

      try {
         for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 2000000; ctr++)
         {
            // Make sure there's no corruption of Random.
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            lock (randLock) {
               result = rand.NextDouble();
            }
            // Check for corruption of Random instance.
            if ((result == previous) && result == 0) {
               source.Cancel();
            }
            else {
               previous = result;
            }
            perThreadCtr++;
            perThreadTotal += result;
         }

         Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} finished execution.",
                           Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
         Console.WriteLine("Random numbers generated: {0:N0}", perThreadCtr);
         Console.WriteLine("Sum of random numbers: {0:N2}", perThreadTotal);
         Console.WriteLine("Random number mean: {0:N4}\n", perThreadTotal/perThreadCtr);

         // Update overall totals.
         lock (numericLock) {
            totalCount += perThreadCtr;
            totalValue += perThreadTotal;
         }
      }
      catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
         Console.WriteLine("Corruption in Thread {1}", e.GetType().Name, Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
      }
      finally {
         countdown.Signal();
      }
   }
}
```

Why would they need a check for corruption? What might be a real life case for checking for Random corruption when I can make sure that all the usages to Random.Next() is locked by a randomizer lock?
How do we mitigate if my shared/static `Random` get corrupted?

Is there any recommendation around this?

Comment: You might have all sorts of problems if some other function uses the same `Random` instance and forgets to use the lock.  Beyond that...?  The only conclusion is that this particular `Random` class is hopelessly broken and you should use a different one.

Comment: I dont really need a real real random. But I dont want Random.Next() to return me 0 every time too. I can make sure that no other method will be using Random.Next without a lock. In that case, is there a problem?

Comment: It looks to me that is it is just checking code -- lets put this in to see if something when wrong -- we don't think there is any way for something to go wrong but we will check anyway.  -- then nothing went wrong but they didn't take the test code out.

Comment: "The Random() constructor uses the default seed value. This is the most common way of instantiating the random number generator.

In .NET Framework, the default seed value is time-dependent. In .NET Core, the default seed value is produced by the thread-static, pseudo-random number generator."   That's what I would do -- create a separate `Random()` instance for each thread but seed them all with output from a shared (under lock) `Random()`.  That way you avoid the problem of seeding multiple objects from the system clock at the same time.

Comment: Yes I read the code -- that check is there to make sure if something goes wrong it will stop and clean up the threads in a nice way.  That will never happen -- as you cans see from the output the example ran 10 million times without issue.

Comment: @BenVoigt. Yeah. But that is about getting better random numbers as output. That is not really my use case. I dont really need  a super good random number. But I just dont want a corrupt Random obj to keep returning 0 like the document says.

Comment: It is not when it is corrupt that it returns 0 it is when you don't use a lock that it will return 0

Comment: Looks like garbage to me. I usually just lock around static Random class.

Comment: @JinsPeter: Well, my suggestion was actually about eliminating contention for the lock.  If the shared RNG is only used for seeds, not for every single random number, then contention will be greatly reduced.  And the not-shared RNGs don't have any concern of corruption.

Comment: _"Why would they need a check for curruption?"_ - for the sake of example? To show that no corruption is happening?

Comment: @Hogan "as you cans see from the output the example ran 10 million times without issue.". Got that now. Thanks

Comment: Note that since .NET 6 you can just use [`Random.Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shared?view=net-7.0) which is  _"a thread-safe Random instance that may be used concurrently from any thread."_

Comment: @GuruStron The Random.Shared.Next() Call still isn't thread safe? Isn't it is just a helper property to use app wide Randomizer?

Comment: @JinsPeter The previous quote is taken from the docs. _"The Random.Shared.Next() Call still isn't thread safe?"_ - why do you think so? _"Isn't it is just a helper property to use app wide Randomizer? "_ - not, it returns [`ThreadSafeRandom`](https://source.dot.net/System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.cs.html#https://source.dot.net/System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.cs.html,f96d9b9c631fb037) which internally uses thread static instances.

Comment: @GuruStron because, MS documentation is talking only about using Random.Next() in a lock.

Comment: @GuruStron  Just looked into the .NET 6 code. It looks like it is safe to use  `Random.Shared.Next()` any way we want. Random.Next itself is virtual and Random.Shared is a `ThreadSafeRandom` type. The Next method is overriden there to allow concurrent usages. ie. You are right.

Comment: @JinsPeter Microsoft docs evolved for quite many years, I would expect that they will have some inconsistencies. Again, docs claim `Random.Shared` to be thread safe *instance*, so it's members should be threadsafe. _"Just looked into the...."_ - yep, exactly what I have written on my previous comment.

Comment: Nowhere is explained how a Random instance can become "corrupt" and why you can detect said corruption by it returning a 0 twice in a row. It's probably a leftover from 20+ year old example documentation.

Comment: @CodeCaster it seems that the zeroes can be still present - try running [this .NET 5 fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DgEE47). Some runs produce too much zeroes. Note that now for seeded random something called `Net5CompatSeedImpl`/`Net5CompatDerivedImpl` [is used](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.cs,37)

Comment: @Guru that's not documented, but observed. Just wondering why.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the next quotes:

> The following example uses the C# `lock` Statement ... to ensure that a single random number generator is accessed by 11 threads in a thread-safe manner.

and

> The example checks whether the random number generator has become corrupted by determining whether two consecutive calls to random number generation methods return 0. If corruption is detected, the example uses the `CancellationTokenSource` object to signal that all threads should be canceled.

My guess would be that the part in question was added for demonstration purposes to show that no corruption is happening.

P.S.

If you can migrate to .NET 6+ - just use [Random.Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shared?view=net-7.0):

> Provides a thread-safe Random instance that may be used concurrently from any thread.

Currently it is implemented via special private [`ThreadSafeRandom`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.cs,f96d9b9c631fb037) class which handles the thread safety via `[ThreadStatic]` instances to prevent need for locking.

Comment: I am not in a position to directly use .NET6+. Migration is ongoing. but I will note this.